# How to Access Session/Variable Value in DataList Bind item in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, session, datalist

I have a DataList which displays the Uploaded files (.jpg,jpeg,gif etc) in a Specific folder say "EmpMainFolder" which contains all Scanned copy of employee Documents. I want to show it in DataList. The Following code works fine when i give Static Folder Name.

Following code Works Fine for Static Folder Name in DataList of .aspx page:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" CellPadding="5" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image Width="100" runat="server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/Uploads/Employee/{0}")%>' />
                <br />

                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbldocnm" runat="server" CommandName="ViewDocument" CommandArgument=**'<%# Bind("Name", "~/Uploads/Employee/{0}") %>'**>View</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
        </asp:DataList>
```

I want to Set the Current Employee Folder Name from Session as:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" CellPadding="5" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image Width="100" runat="server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl=**'<%# Bind("Name", "~/Uploads/Employee/%>'+ '<%#Session["EmpMainFolder"] %>'"+"/"+{0}")%>'** />
            <br />
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' runat="server" /><br />
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbldocnm" runat="server" CommandName="ViewDocument" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Name", "~/Uploads/Employee/{0}") %>'>View</asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <ItemStyle BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center"  VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
</asp:DataList>
```

But, When the Folder Name is set Dynamically through Session it doesn't show any image.

Any Idea?
Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out something like this

```
ImageURL='<%# GetImage((string)Eval("Name")) %>'
```

write down function like this

```
public static string GetImage(string name)
{

        return "~/Uploads/Employee/"+ Session["EmpMainFolder"].ToString() + name;

}
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to create a method if it can be done in the aspx itself?

Comment: @krshekhar - i think its good to have like this if there is any logic you need for getting value in grid column...if its direct value than there is no need of it..

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE - welcome dont forget to upvote answer and mark it as accepted if its work for you...

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Image Width="100" runat="server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Uploads/Employee/"+ Eval("Name").ToString()+"/" +Session["EmpMainFolder"] %>'/>
```

you can use like this. But can you explain what exact are you making in Bind of ImageUrl.
Can you provide a full path of any user and the variable part of the url.

Comment: thanks @krshekhar for replying Modifying your code with some extent it works fine...!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve by Eval

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbldocnm" runat="server" CommandName="ViewDocument" CommandArgument='<%# "~/Uploads/Employee/" +  Session["EmpMainFolder"] + "/" + Eval("Name") %>'>View</asp:LinkButton>
```